# Get element at the specified position in arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have this `arraylist`:

```
List<View> mListViews = new ArrayList<View>();
```

which is populated by

```
addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/a.html");
addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/b.html");
addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/c.html");
```

and the `addView` method:

```
private void addView(List<View> viewList,String url) {
        WebView webView=new WebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        viewList.add(webView);
    }
```

I would like to get the element from the second position in the `arraylist` as a string. So the expected result is `file:///android_asset/b.html`. I tried

```
String test = mListViews.get(1);
```

But I received error incompatible type, required `java.lang.String`, found `android.view.View`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please don't down vote without giving reason. I am a self leaner.

Comment: `List<View>` your list has type `View` then how can you get `String` from its position.

Comment: This problem and the question itself isn't related to anrdoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was my issue, I would do the following:

Create a **model** class...

```
public class ListModel {

    View view;
    String url;

    public ListModel (View view, String url) {
        this.view = view;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Make a **list** that takes in that class...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<ListModel> listModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listModel = new ArrayList<>();

        listModel.add(new ListModel(view, "url"));



    }
}
```

From there you can create a **for loop** to get the view and / or the url..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listModel.size(); i++) {
        View getView = listModel.get(i).getView();
        String getUrl = listModel.get(i).getUrl();
    }
```

Now, keep in mind, my code will NOT work because I didn't create a VIEW to put into the list. But this is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String test = ( (WebView) mListViews.get(1) ).getUrl();
```

Be aware that if you do this before a page has finished loading, test will be `null`.

Another option would be to create a class encapsulating a WebView and the url string, then creating a list of objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

As you write you have `ArrayList` of `View` type.

Result of `mListViews.get(1)` is type of `View`. You can't assign `View` to `String` variable.

Question is for what you creating `ArrayList<View>` and populate it with `WebView`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the url from the webView I think you just need to do this:

```
String test = mListViews.get(1).getURL();
```

Comment: This won't work, because it's a list of View, not WebView.

Comment: Make a List<WebView> or cast it like @SusmitAgrawal did.